Identify movie about young wheelchair-bound boy, fighting against a biker gang

Made in the 1980s, set in the period it was filmed.
A young boy in a wheelchair invents a remote controlled-robot.
I think his dad was absent.
He made friends with a girl.
There was trouble with a biker gang.
He used the robot and his inventing skills to fight the biker gang "via remote control". I remember an A-Team style segment where the boy and girl are getting set up for the "battle". One of their "weapons" was to secretly install a knife in the seat of one of the motorbikes that could be remotely activated to thrust up from the seat.

I don't remember much more, sorry.
